# How to render a thymeleaf template to a String using a security context in String boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I want to render a thymeleaf template to String for use in a JSON return value (returned by the controller).

My code is this and it almost works.

```
//get template engine
    @Autowired
    private ISpringTemplateEngine templateEngine;

//Controller code
        Context context = new Context();
        context.setVariable("dynamicDetailInfo", dynamicDetailInfo);
                String html = templateEngine.process("includes/_fragment", singleton("absenceDynamicDetail"), context);
                System.out.println(html);
```

It doesn't work because the template accesses a security context, and I am only providing a simple Context. This line in the template breaks:

```
sec:authorize="#authentication.principal.getCompany().getPackOrder().isInclTimetrack()"
```

The error message is:

```
Could not obtain authentication object: Thymeleaf context is neither an implementation of IWebContext (for Spring MVC apps) nor ISpringWebFluxContext (for Spring WebFlux apps).
```

How can I acquire such a Context and use it with my Controller code?
Do you know any keywords I could search for?

Answer (score 0):

I added request and response to the Controller endpoint signature.
Then I created a WebContext using this information.
The template now renders, I hope correctly.

The Controller source code now looks like this:

```
    @GetMapping(path = "/dynamicDetailInfo/info", produces = "application/json")
    @PreAuthorize(MA_CMA_CHEF_CONDITION)
    public ResponseEntity<AbsenceDynamicDetailInfo> getDynamicDetail(Model model, @PathVariable Long locationId,
            @ModelAttribute AbsencePostInfo absencePostInfo, @AuthenticationPrincipal ApplicationUser appUser,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        AbsenceDynamicDetailInfo dynamicDetailInfo = absenceService.getDynamicDetailInfo(absencePostInfo, appUser);
        dynamicDetailInfo.clearSensitiveData();
        //
        // Create the WebContext using the request and response objects
        WebContext context = new WebContext(request, response, request.getServletContext(), request.getLocale());
        //Set variables to be used in HTML template
        context.setVariable("dynamicDetailInfo", dynamicDetailInfo);
        // process the template using thymeleaf engine
        String html = templateEngine.process("includes/_fragment", singleton("absenceDynamicDetail"), context);
        dynamicDetailInfo.setHtml(html);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(dynamicDetailInfo);
    }
```